# Can I use dispensers or droppers to auto-replant crops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm working on a fully-automatic farm now that 1.5 is out. The plan is to use redstone to flush fully-grown crops into a channel to be collected by a hopper and then picked up by a cart. The issue I've ran into, however, is that seeds do no seem to be planted by dispensers or droppers. The wiki says bone meal can be used on growing crops from dispensers, but is it possible to plant the crops from either device?

This is my current setup:

[image]

Comment: I use MineFactory Reloaded's Planters and Harvesters for this functionality. It's seriously an exceptional mod. Look into it. My wheat harvester is fully independent. I'd post pictures but I haven't played Minecraft in like two months, I haven't even transferred the files onto this computer yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In vanilla Minecraft, wheat, carrots, and potatoes must be planted by hand, although they can be automatically harvested with water or pistons.

You might be able to get the functionality you want with a mod, but I don't know of any. Sorry!

Comment: Forestry and Thaumcraft both automate harvesting and replanting. This design might also work with RedPower2 deployers, but I have not tried to see if they will place crops (since the Forestry and Thaumcraft methods are easier).

Comment: Redpower can actually plant seeds, and I've seen quite a few builds that use that mechanic. The farms you make like that can be a lot more compact and a lot faster than the other options, as long as you have infinite bone meal to supply your farm with.

Comment: The best mod for planting and harvesting crops is Minefactory Reloaded. Here is a [video covering the mod](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCScuk3NV4I), the first machine group covered is the Planter/Fertilizer/Harvester.

Comment: I'm pretty sure testificates replant crops now.

Comment: @Fambida yes. As of 1.8, Farmer(!) villagers will plant and harvest carrots, potatoes and wheat. Note that they will pick them up themselves unless their inventory is already full. They will also try to share these will other villagers (converting wheat into bread in the process) which can be exploited to create [villager AI farms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VB1n_2bLk4o).

Comment: Since you're mentioning mods, an example for 1.12 (still extensively played modded) is RedstonePlusPlus which gives this functionality to Dispensers.

Answer (score 4):

No, dispenser nor droppers can plant seeds. However, as an alternative you can put a villager farmer there and he will automatically plant seeds.

Answer (score 0):

As of Minecraft 1.8, it is possible to make automatically replant crops using farmer villagers, see [How can I make my farmer villager replant crops? (1.8)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/183703/185203)

Answer (score -5):

You can use

```
/fill xyz xyz minecraft:carrots
```

Comment: You would still need to do that every time