# How can I make my farmer villager replant crops? (1.8)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to the notes for the 1.8 update, farmer villagers will harvest ready crops and replant them. The farmer will hold the produce (wheat, carrots or potatoes) they harvest for up to 6 stacks then it will fall on the ground. Using this information I setup a farm with a hopper minecart running underneath the crops to pick up the items they drop.

I'm having trouble making them harvest crops, even after giving them 6 stacks of each type of crop they can harvest. Am I doing something wrong? Can I make this more efficient?

More info: I made a 4 9x9 field of crops with 2 farmer villagers in it and fenced off.

Comment: You can enslave villagers now? Sweet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw them two more stacks and try again.

According to the "[Villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Farmers)" page on the wiki they will pick up 8 stacks before their inventory is full, not 6:

> The villagers will pick up 8 stacks of items before their “inventory” is full.

After their inventories are full they will stop picking it up:

> After their “inventories” have been filled up, they will continue to tend to crops, but will not pick up anything they collect.

You should also make sure that you have chosen farmer villagers to do the work. It will not go down well if you have chosen a butcher or a librarian to do the farming work. Make sure you farmer villagers they look like this:

[image]

Also, in 1.9 and above, right clicking (trading) with the villager will tell you the profession.  This is important because there are other villagers with plain brown robes now.

Comment: A way to make sure that you have farmers (because there are other villagers with the same skin) is to right click and open the trade window. At the top it will label which type of villager it is.

Comment: I ensured they were farmers. The trade window says "Farmer". I threw them a few more stacks. They were all full. I also got rid of all the doors in the nearby vicinity because they seemed to want to go check them out. Still no luck

Comment: Were they tending to the garden before you threw them the stacks?

Comment: They weren't removing any fully grown crops at all before.

Comment: Did they ever remove any crops? In testing, they don't seem to do it all the time, but they would do some at first and then there would be a delay. It likely will not be a very fast farm.

Comment: I believe the farm needs to be within 16 blocks of a valid house. The wiki seems to say that, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Same set up with the mine cart running under the farm.

I have a Village with about 50 Villagers. It seemed the only thing my farmer wanted to do was get to the other Villagers or get to the center point in the Village. I moved the Farm about 50 blocks from the Village and he now farms.

I put 8 stacks of seeds on a farmer/fisherman/shepherd or fletcher,(any villager with a solid brown robe). I only did Wheat because it's the only one that seems to work with the mine cart under the farm.

Carrots and Potatoes seem to work a little differently with the farmers. 
If you fill the farmers with 8 stacks of carrots or potatoes they wont pick up anything. But they will place it.  So I use water to push the items to a hopper for the carrots and potatoes. The farmer will replant after the flush.

Answer (score 0):

Answer moved from body of question:

---

UPDATE: I threw more stacks at the farmers until they were full. I also removed any doors nearby. I removed some grown crops manually and they did replant. Will see if they harvest too.